# Access json result with spaces

Tags: php, json

I am getting a json result from an API. One of the keys in presented in a question, rather than a true key like this:

```
 {"somthing":"12345","questions":[{"Question Here about something. There are also quotes like this \"here\")":"thevalue"}],"id":"123455"}
```

"Question Here about something. There are also quotes like this \"here\"" 
Will always remain the same, but how to I access its value (thevalue).

I'm trying something like:

```
$result = json_decode($jsonresult);

echo $result->questions->Question Here about something. There are also quotes like this \"here\");
```

But that does not work because of the spaces and escaped quotes. Any suggestions?

Comment: I believe `questions->{"Question here..."}` should give you access to it. Or pass `true` for the second parameter of `json_decode` and access it within the array `$questions["Question Here..."]`

Answer (score 3):

Try Below:

```
$jsonresult  =  '{"somthing":"12345","questions":[{"Question Here about something. There are also quotes like this \"here\")":"thevalue"}],"id":"123455"}';
$result      =  json_decode($jsonresult);
echo $result->questions[0]->{'Question Here about something. There are also quotes like this "here")';
```

This will result `thevalue`

Answer (score 0):

A much easier way is to just convert the JSON string into a PHP associative array like this:

```
$json_string = '{"somthing":"12345","questions":[{"Question Here about something. There are also quotes like this \"here\")":"thevalue"}],"id":"123455"}';   

$json = json_decode($json_string, true);

$questions = $json['questions'];

for($i = 0; $i < count($questions); $i++) {
    $question = $questions[$i];
    foreach($question as $key => $value) {
        echo "Question: " . $key . "\n";
        echo "Answer:" . $value . "\n";
    }
}
```